# Grouping consecutive elements at specified positions

Tags: list-manipulation, functions, performance-tuning, function-construction, built-in-symbols

Let

```
L1={1,2,4,6,8,9,10,14,15,17,21,22,72,76,80,96,106,116,117}
```

**Question1)** Group from 10-th to 14-th elements in `L1`.

So that the output becomes

```
L2={1,2,4,6,8,9,10,14,15,{17,21,22,72,76},80,96,106,116,117}
```

A possible solution is

```
{Splice[L1[[;; 10 - 1]]], L1[[10 ;; 14]], Splice[L1[[14 + 1 ;;]]]}
```

But I believe there is a faster solution, maybe built-in command, because such operation (**grouping consecutive elements at a specified position**) feels so essential, and my solution has somewhat redundant side.

Also I want to deal with case of multiple positions :

**Question 2)** Group from 5-th to 7-th and from 10-th to 14-th and 16th to lists in L.

So that the output becomes

```
{1,2,4,6,{8,9,10},14,15,{17,21,22,72,76},80,{96},106,116,117}
```

Is there a ***fast*** method to achieve it?

The source list can be large and there may be numerous positions to work with, but it is guaranteed that each position is consecutive, and those positions do not overlap each other.

+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-

I posted performances of various answers. Thank you all posters!

Comment: You should submit this as a resource function, when you perfect it. A good question indeed.

Comment: Thank you! I am going to test the performances of answers!

Comment: Please transfer all these stats into an answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
ClearAll[group] ;
group[list_List, start_List, end_List] := Block[
    {copy},
    copy = list ;
    copy[[start]] = Map[Take[list, #] &, Transpose[{start, end}]] ;
    copy[[Flatten[Map[Apply[Range], Transpose[{start + 1, end}]]]]] = Nothing ;
    copy
] ;

L2 == group[L1, {10}, {14}]
L3 == group[L1, {5, 10, 16}, {7, 14, 16}]

(* True *)
(* True *)
```

Comment: Very nice! (+1)

Comment: Good work !!! (+1)

Answer (score 4):

TakeDrop might be interesting to you:

```
TakeDrop[L1, {10, 14}]
(*gives {{17, 21, 22, 72, 76}, {1, 2, 4, 6, 8, 9, 10, 14, 15, 80, 96, 106, 116, 117}}*)
```

From there you can use Insert:

```
Insert[#2, #1, 10] & @@ TakeDrop[L1, {10, 14}]
(*gives result for question 1*)
```

This gets awkward with multiple grouping specs.

Another approach would be to insert markers and then use SequenceReplace:

```
markedL1 = Insert[L1, Mark, {{5}, {8}, {10}, {15}, {16}, {17}}]
SequenceReplace[markedL1, {Mark, group : Except[Mark] ..., Mark} :> {group}]
(*gives result for question 2*)
```

Here's another similar approach:

```
taggedL1 = SubsetMap[f, L1, Join[Range[10, 14], Range[5, 7], Range[16, 16]]];
SequenceReplace[taggedL1, g : {__f} :> First /@ g]
```

You can see how you'd construct the Join[...] expression from your desired ranges.

Anyway, I fiddled with several ways to do this, but I didn't find a built-in command.

Answer (score 3):

**2nd attempt**

```
L1 = {1, 2, 4, 6, 8, 9, 10, 14, 15, 17, 21, 22, 72, 76, 80, 96, 106, 
  116, 117}
```

Here I specify ranges (not in order but non-overlapping)

```
pos = List /@ # & /@ {Range[10, 14], Range[5, 7] , Range[16, 16]}
```

and I insert `{ }` at these positions so the counting is not messed up.

```
alist = ReplacePart[L1, # -> {} & /@ pos]
```

> ```
> {1, 2, 4, 6, {}, {}, {}, 14, 15, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, 80, {}, 106, \
> 116, 117}
> ```

```
items = Extract[L1, #] & /@ pos
```

> ```
> {{17, 21, 22, 72, 76}, {8, 9, 10}, {96}}
> ```

```
posx = pos[[All, 1]]
```

> ```
> {{10}, {5}, {16}}
> ```

```
ReplacePart[alist, 
  posx[[#]] -> items[[#]] & /@ Range[1, Length@items]] /. {} -> 
  Nothing
```

> ```
> {1, 2, 4, 6, {8, 9, 10}, 14, 15, {17, 21, 22, 72, 
>   76}, 80, {96}, 106, 116, 117}
> ```

---

**Original incorrect attempt**

Doing only 1 replacement of the sequence even if multiple such sequences are present:

```
SequenceReplace[L1, L1[[10 ;; 14]] :> L1[[10 ;; 14]], 1]
```

> ```
> {1, 2, 4, 6, 8, 9, 10, 14, 15, {17, 21, 22, 72, 
>   76}, 80, 96, 106, 116, 117}
> ```

Case of multiple sequence replacement:

```
SequenceReplace[L1, {
  L1[[5 ;; 7]] :> L1[[5 ;; 7]]
  , L1[[10 ;; 14]] :> L1[[10 ;; 14]]
  , L1[[16 ;; 16]] :> L1[[16 ;; 16]]
  }
 ]
```

> ```
> {1, 2, 4, 6, {8, 9, 10}, 14, 15, {17, 21, 22, 72, 
>   76}, 80, {96}, 106, 116, 117}
> ```

Comment: Thank you, but I think this solution does not work for list like `L1 = {1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1}`. And I also bet the performance is not so good because the solution search some patterns.

Comment: You are right. I will delete the answer for now and try to come up with something better.

Answer (score 3):

You may use [`FoldPairList`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FoldPairList.html) with [`TakeList`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TakeList.html).

`subGroups` takes the list and the start and end indices of each group.

```
subGroups[list_, groupPos_] :=
 Module[
  {sg}
  , sg =
   Flatten@
    FoldPairList[
     {
       {First@#2 - #1 - 1, Subtract @@ Reverse@#2 + 1}
       , Last@#2
       } &
     , 0
     , Sort@groupPos
     ]
  ; sg = TakeList[list, Flatten@{sg, Length@list - Total@sg}]
  ; MapAt[Apply[Sequence], sg, List /@ Range[1, Length@sg, 2]]
  ]
```

With `L1` in OP

```
subGroups[L1, {{10, 14}}]
```

> ```
> {1, 2, 4, 6, 8, 9, 10, 14, 15, {17, 21, 22, 72, 76}, 80, 96, 106, 116, 117}
> ```

and

```
subGroups[L1, {{5, 7}, {10, 14}, {16, 16}}]
```

> ```
> {1, 2, 4, 6, {8, 9, 10}, 14, 15, {17, 21, 22, 72, 76}, 80, {96}, 106, 116, 117}
> ```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

I try to write a function to obtain list fractured with another list of points of fracture...

```
        Clear["Global`*"]
miLista[lista_List, filtro_List] := 
 Module[{final = {}, i, j, k, provisional = {}},
  (* if max{filtro] > Length[lista] error  SALIR *)
  If[Max[filtro] > Length[lista],
   Print["filtro has elemnts bigger than length of lista"];
   Return[49404390548]];
  (* si filtro no está ordenado  error  SALIR *)
  If[! OrderedQ[filtro],
   Print["filtro must be sorted"];
   Return[49404390548]];
  For[i = 1, i <= Length[filtro], i++,
   If[i == 1, (* solo los primeros elementos de lista *)
    For[j = 1, j < filtro[[i]], j++,
     AppendTo[final, lista[[j]]]];
    k = j,
    If[EvenQ[i],            
     {provisional = {};
      For[j = k, j <= filtro[[i]], j++,
       provisional = AppendTo[provisional, lista[[j]]]];
      AppendTo[final, provisional];
      k = j;
      },         
     {For[j = k, j < filtro[[i]], j++,
       AppendTo[final, lista[[j]]]];
      k = j;
      }
     ]
    ]
   ];
  For[j = k, j <= Length[lista], j++,             (* 
   el resto de los elementos de lista *)
   AppendTo[final, lista[[j]]]];
  Return[final];
  ]
```

tested it with

```
 miLista[Range[36], {3, 11, 16, 18, 21, 21, 29, 33}]
```

and gave

{1,2,{3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11},12,13,14,15,{16,17,18},19,20,{21},22,23,24,25,26,27,28,{29,30,31,32,33},34,35,36}

Answer (score 1):

**-1>** Today (2022.3.19) I was able to find even faster and intuitive way to achieve it. Thanks for Edmund's introduction of `TakeList` command. The prerequisite for `L` and `P` are similar to **0>**.

```
L = Range[3300000]; P = Partition[Prime[Range[220000]], 2];

imdaK2[L_, P_] := 
 Module[{Q, P2}, Q = Join @@ P; P2 = 2 Range[Length[P]] - 1;
  Q[[P2]] += -1;
  Q2 = TakeList[L, Differences[Append[Prepend[Q, 0], Length[L]]]];
  ReplacePart[
   Q2, {#, 0} & /@ (Append[P2, 2 Length[P] + 1]) -> Sequence]]

imdaK2[L, P]; // Timing

{0.359375, Null}
```

[image]

**0>** This is a variation of I.M. A little faster then I.M.'s method.
Here, `X` is a list and `P` must be a ordered set of ordered pair of positive integers, which looks like
`{{p1,p2},{p3,p4},{p5,p6},...,{p(2k-1),p(2k)}}` should satisfy
`p1<=p2 < p3<=p4 < p5<=p6<`,... and `p(2k) <= Length[X]`.

```
imdaK[X_, P_] := Module[{tran, accu, Q, Y}, tran = Transpose[P];
  accu = Accumulate[tran[[1]] - Join[{0}, Drop[tran[[2]], -1]]];
  Q = Range @@@ P;
  Y = X;
  Y[[accu]] = (X[[#]] & /@ (Q));
  Y[[Complement[Range[accu[[-1]] - P[[-1, 2]] + Length[X]], accu]]] = 
   X[[Complement[Range[Length[X]], Join @@ Q]]];
  Y]
```

[image]

**1>** Anxon Pués's solution for `Range[30000]` and `Prime[Range[3000]]` took 0.78 seconds. But practically not applicable for `Range[3300000]` and `Prime[Range[220000]]`

[image]

**2>** Syed's solution code is like

```
Syed[L1_, px_] := Module[{pxran, pos, alist, items, posx},
  pxran = Range @@@ px;
  pos = List /@ # & /@ px;
  alist = ReplacePart[L1, # -> {} & /@ pos];
  items = Extract[L1, #] & /@ pos;
  posx = pos[[All, 1]];
  ReplacePart[alist, 
    posx[[#]] -> items[[#]] & /@ Range[1, Length@items]] /. {} -> 
    Nothing]
```

for `Range[3300000]` and `Prime[Range[220000]]` it took 1.96 seconds :

[image]

**3>** lericr's first method took 1.76 seconds for `Range[1000]` and `Prime[Range[160]]`. Practically not applicable for `Range[3300000]` and `Prime[Range[220000]]`

```
markedL1 = 
  Insert[Range[1000], Mark, 
   Splice[{{Prime[2 # - 1]}, {Prime[2 #] + 1}}] & /@ Range[80]];
SequenceReplace[
   markedL1, {Mark, group : Except[Mark] ..., 
     Mark} :> {group}]; // Timing
```

[image]

**4>** lericr's second method took 6.73 seconds for `Range[1000]` and `Prime[Range[80]]`. We see not practical for large list. Not very important but note that we should make `f` Listable to make the code work properly.

```
lericr2[L1_, px_] := Module[{taggedL1, tempf, tempg},
  taggedL1 = 
   SubsetMap[Function[x, tempf[x], Listable], L1, 
    Join @@ (Range @@@ px)];
  SequenceReplace[taggedL1, tempg : {__tempf} :> First /@ tempg]]

lericr2[Range[1000], Partition[Prime[Range[160]], 2]]; // Timing
```

[image]

**5>** I.M. 's method : For `Range[3300000]` and `Prime[Range[220000]]`, it took 1.06 seconds.

```
ClearAll[group];
group[list_List,start_List,end_List]:=Block[{copy},copy=list;
copy[[start]]=Map[Take[list,#]&,Transpose[{start,end}]];
copy[[Flatten[Map[Apply[Range],Transpose[{start+1,end}]]]]]=Nothing;
copy];
group[Range[3300000],Prime[2Range[110000]-1],Prime[2Range[110000]]];//Timing
```

[image]

**6>** Edmund's method took 1.31 seconds for `Range[300000]` and `Prime[Range[25000]]`, but didn't work for larger case, `Range[3300000]` and `Prime[Range[220000]]`.

```
subGroups[list_, groupPos_] := Module[{sg}, sg = Flatten@FoldPairList[
      {{First@#2 - #1 - 1, Subtract @@ Reverse@#2 + 1}, Last@#2} &, 0,
       Sort@groupPos]; 
   sg = TakeList[list, Flatten@{sg, Length@list - Total@sg}]; 
   MapAt[Apply[Sequence], sg, List /@ Range[1, Length@sg, 2]]];
subGroups[Range[300000], Partition[Prime[Range[25000]], 2]]; // Timing
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

**Question 1:**

```
list =
  {1, 2, 4, 6, 8, 9, 10, 14, 15, 17, 21, 22, 72, 76, 80, 96, 106, 116, 117};

Sublist1[{a_, b_}][dt_] :=
 Join @@ MapAt[List, 2] @ TakeList[dt, {a - 1, b - a + 1, All}]

Sublist1[{10, 14}] @ list
```

{1, 2, 4, 6, 8, 9, 10, 14, 15, {17, 21, 22, 72, 76}, 80, 96, 106, 116, 117}

```
Sublist1[{1, 1}] @ list
```

{{1}, 2, 4, 6, 8, 9, 10, 14, 15, 17, 21, 22, 72, 76, 80, 96, 106, 116, 117}

**Question 2:**

```
Sublist2[p_][dt_] :=
 Module[{od},
  od = ReplaceAt[dt, _ :> Missing[], List /@ Flatten @ MapApply[Range] @ p];
  Table[od[[p[[All, 1]][[i]]]] = Map[Take[dt, #] &, p][[i]], {i, Length @ p}];
  DeleteMissing @ od]

 Sublist2[{{5, 7}, {10, 14}, {16, 16}}] @ list
```

{1, 2, 4, 6, {8, 9, 10}, 14, 15, {17, 21, 22, 72,
76}, 80, {96}, 106, 116, 117}

With `Sublist2` we can replicate the functionality of `Sublist1`:

```
Sublist2[{{10, 14}}] @ list
```

{1, 2, 4, 6, 8, 9, 10, 14, 15, {17, 21, 22, 72,
76}, 80, 96, 106, 116, 117}